# I want to add the transition on expanding or collapsing the table row onClick handler in React

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a plain HTML table. I have a list of elements that I am displaying, and all <| tr> tag has a button to display some extra information by clicking on it. The transform: rotate property is working for the icon button but not working on expanding the row.

User.tsx

```
          <div className="user-table-container">
            <table className="user-table">
              <thead>
                <tr className="user-table-row">
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Open</th>
                  <th>Role</th>
                  <th>Active</th>
                  <th>Created At</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {allUsers.map((user) => {
                  return <UserList key={user._id} displayAll={seeAll}  {...user} />;
                })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

UserList.tsx

```
const UserList = ({ displayAll, ...user }: UserListProps) => {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (displayAll) setExpand(true);
    else setExpand(false);
  }, [displayAll]);

  const handleExpand = () => setExpand(!expand);

  return (
    <>
      <tr className="user-table-row">
        <td>{user.username}</td>
        <td>{user.email}</td>
        <td>
          <IconButton
            className={`icon ${expand ? "open" : ""}`}
            onClick={handleExpand}
          >
            <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </td>
        <td>{user.roles}</td>
        <td>{user.isActive ? "Yes" : "No"}</td>
        <td>{new Date(user.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}</td>
      </tr>

// This is the extra information I want to display on button click
      {expand && (
        <tr className={`user_row ${expand ? "opened" : ""}`}>
          <td colSpan={6}>Id: {user._id}</td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

// Css file

```
.user-table {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 20px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 2px groove lightsteelblue;
}
.user-table-row>th,
.user-table-row>td,
.user_row>td {
   margin: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px groove lightsteelblue;
   padding: 20px;
   text-align: left;
}
.icon {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: all 0.25s;
}
.icon.open {
   transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.user_row {
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: height 0.5s ease;
}
.user_row.opened {
   height: 100px;
}
```

The .icon className property is working, it's rotating the icon to 180deg. But the transition on row expanding or closing is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [this link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/collapse-table-row-plpz8d?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr50r0xh00063b6i8re7c2ih%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr50r0xh00023b6i10y3oft2%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr50r0xh00033b6if1caba8t%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr50r0xh00053b6ie1isxq58%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr50r0xh00023b6i10y3oft2%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr50r0xh00023b6i10y3oft2%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr50tpqi00023b6ixfdeajxk%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A5%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A51%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A5%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A51%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr51zv5i01lf3b6iiatb6o37%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A6%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A11%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A6%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A11%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles.css%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr50tpqi00023b6ixfdeajxk%2522%257D%252C%2522clr50r0xh00053b6ie1isxq58%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr50r0xh00053b6ie1isxq58%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr523yhr01ni3b6i0fxplucu%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr50r0xh00043b6i8gz8kc4s%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522SANDBOX_INFO%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr523yhr01ni3b6i0fxplucu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clr50r0xh00033b6if1caba8t%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr50r0xh00033b6if1caba8t%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D). don't use condition to hide row, use `.close` and `.open` css classes.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `open&&`condition in your js. because you already handle it by `overflow:hidden` in your css.

just remove `open&&` from your code and your transition will work well.
By the way, 12s is a very long time.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but it doesn't work. I know that 12s is a very long time just added it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The css seems fine, probably the problem is in the `handleExpand` function.

You can try to implement that way:

```
const [expand, setExpand] = useState({});
const handleExpand = (rowId) => {
    setExpand({ ...expand, [rowId]: !expand[rowId] });
};
```

I created a working example, so you can follow this approach:

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/shy-paper-ld4vmy?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr459vk10006356htknr87zb%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr459vk10002356hbqv3gpqa%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr459vk10003356hhvcg5p9p%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr459vk10005356h891sha2k%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr459vk10002356hbqv3gpqa%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr459vk00001356hb2wf2h8m%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr45akbd004t356hme5yj6og%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A5%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A5%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A8%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A11%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr459vk10002356hbqv3gpqa%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr45akbd004t356hme5yj6og%2522%257D%252C%2522clr459vk10005356h891sha2k%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr459vk10004356h16kgv74q%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr459vk10005356h891sha2k%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr459vk10004356h16kgv74q%2522%257D%252C%2522clr459vk10003356hhvcg5p9p%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr459vk10003356hhvcg5p9p%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: Is your code working?

See this example:- [Example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/xenodochial-silence-l6jgly?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A63%2C39)

Comment: Yes, click in the arrow and you will see the row expanding.